# What exactly constitutes a measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse, decoherence

As far as I understand it, quantum mechanics only predicts the probabilities of finding a system in some state of some observable when we make a measurement.

So, what exactly constitutes a measurement that will make the system to collapse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What constitutes an observation/measurement in QM?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43406/)