# The "observer effect": is this a basic law of every observation or measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers, measurements, interactions

I would appreciate some clarification of the "observer effect":

Is it generally true that **every** observation (or measurement) disturbs the object being observed?

I understand the observer effect is especially relevant at quantum scales and may be often negligible at larger scales.  But in principle is it true that observing **any** system amounts to an interaction and inevitable disturbance of that system?

And if that's true, is it obviously true that the interaction also disturbs the observer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What constitutes an observation/measurement in QM?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43406/)